# Столкновение объектов

Tags: c++builder

Есть 3 класса: TWolf, TRabbit, TBall
TBall - создается в методе класса TRabbit. Объекты класса TBall перемещаются к объектам класса TWolf. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при столкновении этих объектов, оба удалялись
Я хочу, чтобы это обрабатывалось в классе TWolf, но не представляю, как это реализовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: В чем возникает сложность? Вам надо передать массив объектов TBall каждому TWolf и проверить, не находится ли какой-то из TBall в хитбоксе(зоне поражения) TWolf.

Comment: @AlexKrass объекты TBall создаются каждые пол секунды, и объектов TWolf больше 10. Мне кажется, система немного "нагнется"

Comment: Не должна, даже если у Вас 10.000 шаров на 100 волков, это всего 1.000.000 итераций, что для С++ должно проходить достаточно быстро считая простую проверку на столкновения(пересечение окружностей или пересечение прямоугольников). По крайней мере 60 FPS с этим отлично справится и даже не подавится, больше уйдет на рисование самой этой графики.

Comment: @AlexKrass а если объекты TBall создаются в методе объекта TRabbit?

Comment: Не важно, где они создаются. Тут вопрос в том, что придется брать одни объекты и вторые объекты, сравнивая их свойства. А значит надо продумать, как их для этого получать, т.к.у Вас должен быть к ним доступ. Я бы на самом деле завел какой-нибудь менеджер объектов и хранил в нем глобальные коллекции. Хотя не знаю, насколько это будет правильно.